# ¿Cómo enviar una clase con objetos a un customAdapter en Android Studio?

Tags: android, customadapter

Me estoy iniciando en Android y tengo el siguiente problema.
Estoy usando varios Arrays donde la posición de sus elementos tienen relación entre ellos (pos 2 del array 1 está relacionada con la pos 2 del array 2) y no es muy funcional ya que va a ser un lio cuando tenga más elementos.

¿Cómo puedo crear una clase con diferentes objetos y pasarlos en vez de pasar cada string?

Tengo esto:

```
String Operaciones[] = {"Sumas I", "Restas I", "Números I"};
String Exps[] = {"80", "110", "60"};
String Sabidurias[] = {"5", "10", "3"};
int Botones[] = {android.R.drawable.ic_media_play, android.R.drawable.ic_media_play,android.R.drawable.ic_media_play};
```

Y quiero que todos los datos estén en un array para que cuando muestre el elemento 1 me aparezca que se llama "Suma 1", con un valor de Exp "80", una sabiduria de "5" y su correspondiente imagen de boton.

Agrego que estos datos los estaba pasando a un customAdapter para mostrarlos en una lista:

```
...
        lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        CustomAdapter adaptador = new CustomAdapter(this, Operaciones, Exps, Sabidurias, Botones);
        lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
...
```

y el getView del customAdapter donde muestro los datos:

```
textOp.setText(Operaciones[i]);
textExp.setText(Exps[i]);
textSabiduria.setText(Sabidurias[i]);
buttonAct.setImageResource(Botones[i]);
```

Si es necesario que deje el código completo solo decírmelo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es tan complicado, solo tienes que declarar una clase a partir de la cual crearas los objetos que almacenaran los valores que utilizaras en los items del `ListView`.

```
public class Operacion {

    String operacion;
    String exp;
    String sabiduria;
    int recurso;

    public Operacion(String operacion, String exp, String sabiduria, int recurso) {
        this.operacion = operacion;
        this.exp = exp;
        this.sabiduria = sabiduria;
        this.recurso = recurso;
    }

    public String getOperacion() {
        return operacion;
    }

    public String getExp() {
        return exp;
    }

    public String getSabiduria() {
        return sabiduria;
    }

    public int getRecurso() {
        return recurso;
    }
}
```

Después creas los objetos de tipo `Operacion`, los agregas a una lista del mismo tipo y por ultimo pasas ésa lista al adaptador del ListView.

```
// ...

// Creas los objetos de tipo Operaciones
Operacion operacion1 = new Operacion("Sumas I", "80", "5");
Operacion operacion2 = new Operacion("Sumas I", "80", "5");
Operacion operacion3 = new Operacion("Sumas I", "80", "5");

// Agregas los objetos a la lista
List<Operacion> operaciones = new ArrayList<>();
operaciones.add(operacion1);
operaciones.add(operacion2);
operaciones.add(operacion3);

lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

// Pasas la lista al adaptador
CustomAdapter adaptador = new CustomAdapter(this, operaciones);

lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
// ...
```

En tu adaptador recibes las lista y asignas sus valores a los items del ListView.

Recibes la lista

```
Context context;
List<Operacion> operaciones;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Operacion> operaciones) {
    this.context = context;
    this.operaciones = operaciones;
}
```

Asignas los valores de la lista a los item del ListView

```
// ...
textOp.setText(operaciones.get(i).getOperacion());
textExp.setText(operaciones.get(i).getExp());
textSabiduria.setText(operaciones.get(i).getSabiduria());
buttonAct.setImageResource(operaciones.get(i).getRecurso());
// ...
```

---

Veo que publicaste una respuesta en la que utilizas un array bidimencional para almacenar los datos que pasas al ListView. Ése no es el mejor enfoque en un lenguaje de programación orientado a objetos. Para que entiendas mejor que son, como funcionan y como utilizar los objetos te recomiendo leer el siguiente articulo de la documentación oficial de Java.

[Objetos (The Java™ Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html)

---

Veo que en tu código no estas siguiendo las mejores practicas de programación. Como por ejemplo, al declarar las variables con mayúsculas.

```
String Operaciones[] = {"Sumas I", "Restas I", "Números I"};
```

Las variables por convención se declaran en minúscula para evitar confusión con las clases.

```
String operaciones[] = {"Sumas I", "Restas I", "Números I"};
```

En estos artículos se explican algunas convenciones utilizadas en el lenguaje de programación Java.

- [Declaración de clases](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html)
- [Declaración de variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)
- [Declaración de métodos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ya he encontrado lo que quería:

```
static final String Operaciones[][] =
            {
                  { "Sumas I", "80","5" },
                  { "Restas I","110","2" },
                  { "Números I","50","7" }
            };
```